# Paypal Adaptive(Chained) Payment with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

It is known that PayPal supports Adaptive(Chained) payments where one buyer sends the money and it is processed using one API account holder and the money can be sent to multiple 
users.

My question is,

1. Does this approach also supports
   accepting credit card (for the
   buyer)?
2. Is it possible to capture the card
   details at our website and use the
   API (in the backend) without
   redirecting to PayPal website
   itself?

Here is my requirement...
I am running a website where sellers can sell their products and buyers buy them.
Seller sets the price and i get a commission

Eg. Person A sells Product P for $100. (My commission is 2%)

Person B buys P. and makes the payment in my website itself. Using Paypal API, i want to process B's credit card and charge him $100. Get my share of $2 and send rest of $98 to Person A.

thanks in advance,

Kannan R

Answer (score 4):

Q1. YES it is possible to accept credit cards (PapPal Adaptive payments supports Guest Payments... where the user can enter their credit card details.

Q2. YES. In continuation of answer to Q1, the credit card details entered acts as the explicitly approved payment hence no need to redirect the sender to Paypal website for authorization.

http://www.paypal-labs.com/TechDocs/

This link explains things better, check out for the Guest Payments link..

Hope it helps.

rgds,
Sourcebits Team.

Comment: the link is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

For Question #2:

While it is possible to capture the credit card details on your site, you should be aware that there is something called [PCI Compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/hardware_software/), which is basically a set of rules you need to follow to ensure that your server and your software is secure.

It is not easy to meet PCI requirements on your own (time, consultant costs, regular inspections, understanding the rules etc.). And if the rules are violated or your server is hacked you could be fined hundreds of dollars/rupees *per* "lost" credit card details.

Search [SO for some good information about this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=storing+credit+card+pci)

Comment: I Understand the complexities of PCI Compliance, but i am not going to store the info anywhere. just not to disclose that paypal is involved or in other words i dont want to redirect my customers out of my website ;)

Comment: Very shortly (if it doesn't already), PCI compliance will apply to more than just /storage/ of credit card data. I have heard that the network the data passes through has special conditions applied for example.

Comment: @KannanR, if credit card details every reach your website (such as in a form hosted on your website), you *still* have to be PCI compliant. For example, take a look at "Credit Card Data Security" under "Full Comparision" link on this page: https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/compare_wp_products#panel14